# File showing in Sources tab but not in Network

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-devtools

I'm verifying that I'm using minified JavaScript in Chrome. I've cleared my cache and loaded the page. In the Sources tab I see:

[image]

But on the Network tab (note the filter) I see only:

[image]

I have not found the unminified angular.js referenced anywhere, and the Network tab does not show it as loaded. As far as I can tell I don't have any workspace folders added. Is this file actually being loaded? If so, how can I determine from where?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it - this is because of the [Source Maps in DevTools](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/debug/readability/source-maps#source-maps-in-devtools-sources-panel) feature. As a .map file named angular.min.js.map existed, Chrome loaded the original source file in addition to the minified one.